# How do I make a SwiftUI gesture that keeps running code while the view is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a button that controls a counter.  If you tap it, the counter goes up by one. But if you tap and hold it, I want the counter to go up by one every n seconds while you are holding it and keep doing that until you let go.

If I use code like:

```
@GestureState var isDetectingLongPress = false
var plusLongPress: some Gesture {
    LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1)
        .updating($isDetectingLongPress) { currentstate, gestureState, _ in
            gestureState = currentstate
        }
        .onEnded { finished in
            print("LP: finished \(finished)")
        }
}
```

Then `isDetectingLongPress` becomes true after one second and then immediately becomes false. And the print in `onEnded` is called after 1 second as well.

I want some way to keep calling code to continuously update a counter while the finger is pressing the view -- not just once after a long press is detected.

Comment: Update: I'm getting somewhere with a LongPressGesture sequenced with a DragGesture -- but I am not really dragging (the finger won't move), so I don't get updating calls.  I think I can start a timer though -- if I figure it out, I'll post a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use instead the following combination to track continuous pressing down

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
@GestureState var isLongPress = false // will be true till tap hold

var plusLongPress: some Gesture {
    LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1).sequenced(before:   
          DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: 
          .local)).updating($isLongPress) { value, state, transaction in
            switch value {
                case .second(true, nil):
                    state = true
                   // side effect here if needed
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting continuous callbacks, but if you combine this with `let timer = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 0.25, runLoop: .main, mode: .common).autoconnect()` and an `.onReceive(timer) { _ in ...` then you can monitor the `isLongPress` in the timer and update the counter only when it's held

Comment: why does it need to be sequenced with a drag gesture?

Comment: The `LongPressGesture` will end after a short while without sequencing it with the drag gesture. The `DragGesture` keeps the gesture alive for the entire length of the touch down

Answer (score 5):

`DragGesture` has `onChanged` and `onEnded`.

Just add this to your `View`.

```
@State private var isPaused = false

.gesture(
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
        .onChanged({ _ in
            isPaused = true
        })
        .onEnded({ _ in
            isPaused = false
        })
)
```

You can add it as a `simultaneousGesture` to a `Button`.

You can use a [ViewModifier](https://gist.github.com/gabrieltheodoropoulos/59dc104163b5718018c6c55309b110fb) to beautify it from [this](https://serialcoder.dev/text-tutorials/swiftui/handle-press-and-release-events-in-swiftui/) article.