# SwiftUI: Longpress Gesture Hold for only 1 Second

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture

Using the Long press gestures on SwiftUI only keep the long press hold gesture for 1 second then automatically releases the long press. I would like for the user to press up to 1 minute or more. Is this possible and how can it be done.

Check out my code below, which currently only supports a 1-second duration long-press gesture.

```
    struct IgnitionDriveView: View {
    
    @GestureState private var drivingGestureState = false
    @GestureState private var reverseGestureState = false
    @State private var showDriveAlert = true
    @State private var showOutOfGasAlert = false
    @State var distanceCovered: Float = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let circleShape = Circle()
        let driveGesture = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1)
            .updating($drivingGestureState) { (currentState, gestureState, transaction) in
                gestureState = currentState
            }.onChanged { _ in
                if distanceCovered < 1000 {
                    self.distanceCovered += 10
                } else {
                    showOutOfGasAlert = true
                }
            }
        
        let reverseGesture = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1)
            .updating($reverseGestureState) { (currentState, gestureState, transaction) in
                gestureState = currentState
            }.onChanged { _ in
                if distanceCovered > 0 {
                    self.distanceCovered -= 10
                }
            }
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Distance Covered in Km: \(distanceCovered)")
                .font(.headline)
            ProgressView(value: distanceCovered > 0 ? distanceCovered : 0, total: 1000)
                .frame(height: 40)
            
            HStack {
                ZStack {
                    circleShape.strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))

                    circleShape
                        .fill(drivingGestureState ? .white : .red)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    
                    Text("D")
                        .bold()
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .font(.title)
                }.foregroundColor(.green)
                    .gesture(driveGesture)
                
                Spacer()
                
                ZStack {
                    circleShape.strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))

                    circleShape
                        .fill(reverseGestureState ? .white : .red)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    
                    Text("R")
                        .bold()
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .font(.title)
                }.foregroundColor(.green)
                    .gesture(reverseGesture)
                    
            }.padding()
        }.alert("Press D to Drive and R to Reverse", isPresented: $showDriveAlert) {
            Button("Okay") { showDriveAlert = false }
        }.alert("You ran out of Gas, Reverse to Gas Station", isPresented: $showOutOfGasAlert) {
            Button("Sucks, but fine!") { showOutOfGasAlert = false }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: 1 minute is 60 seconds.

Comment: Increasing the minimum prolongs the long-press but updates are not delivered to updating() while the user is pressing the view.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524230/12299030?

Comment: can you explain exactly what you want to achieve, rather than say 
"I would like for the user to press up to 1 minute or more.". 
What exactly do you want to "update", staring when ending when?

Comment: I want the counter [distanceCovered] to be updated [increased/decreased] as long as the user is pressing the view and to have the value update the progressview value till the counter hits 1000. Hope that's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a very basic approach that you can build on, based on the code in:

https://adampaxton.com/make-a-press-and-hold-fast-forward-button-in-swiftui/

```
struct IgnitionDriveView: View {
    
    @State private var timer: Timer?
    @State var isLongPressD = false
    @State var isLongPressR = false
    
    @State private var showDriveAlert = true
    @State private var showOutOfGasAlert = false
    @State var distanceCovered: Float = 0.0

    private func circleShape(isPressed: Binding<Bool>) -> some View  {
        Button(action: {
            if isPressed.wrappedValue {
                isPressed.wrappedValue.toggle()
                timer?.invalidate()
            }
        }) {
            ZStack {
                Circle().strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
                Circle().fill(isPressed.wrappedValue ? .white : .red)
            }.frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Distance Covered in Km: \(distanceCovered)").font(.headline)
            ProgressView(value: distanceCovered > 0 ? distanceCovered : 0, total: 1000).frame(height: 40)
            
            HStack {
                ZStack {
                    circleShape(isPressed: $isLongPressD)
                    .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.2).onEnded { _ in
                        isLongPressD = true
                        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                            if distanceCovered < 1000 {
                                distanceCovered += 10
                            } else {
                                showOutOfGasAlert = true
                            }
                        })
                    })
                    
                    Text("D").bold().padding().foregroundColor(.green).font(.title)
                }.foregroundColor(.green)
                
                Spacer()
                
                ZStack {
                    circleShape(isPressed: $isLongPressR)
                    .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.2).onEnded { _ in
                        isLongPressR = true
                        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                            if distanceCovered > 0 {
                                distanceCovered -= 10
                            }
                        })
                    })
                    
                    Text("R").bold().padding().foregroundColor(.blue).font(.title)
                }.foregroundColor(.green)
                
            }.padding()
        }.alert("Press D to Drive and R to Reverse", isPresented: $showDriveAlert) {
            Button("Okay") { showDriveAlert = false }
        }.alert("You ran out of Gas, Reverse to Gas Station", isPresented: $showOutOfGasAlert) {
            Button("Sucks, but fine!") { showOutOfGasAlert = false }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @workingdog i think ultimately what I was missing was using a Timer and simultaneousGesture. Let me give it a run, look at the docs to understand what is different with the code. But I think this is the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

The LongPressGesture is updating after the minimum time no matter if the user lifts its finger or not. Take a look here on how to register to the onEnded even which I guess is what you want to wait for. i.e when the user takes his/hers finger off screen - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/longpressgesture

Comment: I want the Longpress to continue updating even before user releases the long press. onEnded just seems to delay the updates until user releases the long press.

Comment: I see. This is not the use case of LongPressGesture. You will have to use it to trigger a detection of the start and end events. And use a timer or some other method once the trigger is detected

Comment: Thanks @CloudBalancing, I think using a timer will ultimately help me achieve my expectation of how it should work. Can you checkout workingdog 's answer  above ? I think  its taking the approach of using a timer.